# MySQL count, left join, group by to return zero rows

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

In the below sql statement:

```
 SELECT `keywords`.keyID, count(`keywords-occurencies`.keyID) as countOccurencies 
                    FROM `keywords-occurencies`  
                    LEFT JOIN `keywords` 
                    ON `keywords-occurencies`.keyID = `keywords`.keyID 
                    WHERE `keywords-occurencies`.`keyID` IN (1,2,3) AND date BETWEEN '2013/01/25' AND '2013/01/27'
                    GROUP BY `keywords`.`keyID`
```

If keyID 3 has no return values it is not counted as 0 and it is not included in the result set and a result like this is displayed

```
keyID countOccurencies
1       3
3       5
```

I would like to display the zero results like

```
keyID countOccurencies
1       3
2       0
3       5
```

Sample data to test with:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `keywords`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keywords` (
  `keyID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyName` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`keyID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `keywords`
--

INSERT INTO `keywords` (`keyID`, `keyName`) VALUES
(1, 'testKey1'),
(2, 'testKey2');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `keywords-occurencies`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keywords-occurencies` (
  `occurencyID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `keyID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`occurencyID`),
  KEY `keyID` (`keyID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `keywords-occurencies`
--

INSERT INTO `keywords-occurencies` (`occurencyID`, `keyID`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2013-01-27'),
(2, 1, '2013-01-26');

--
-- Constraints for table `keywords-occurencies`
--
ALTER TABLE `keywords-occurencies`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `keywords@002doccurencies_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`keyID`) REFERENCES `keywords` (`keyID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

things to do

- you should be grouping it with  `GROUP BY keywords-occurencies.keyID`
- and you must be displaying `keywords-occurencies.keyID` not the `keywords.keyID`
- COUNT `keywords.keyID`
- (*optional*) use `ALIAS` so you can get rid of the backticks other than tableNames

query,

```
SELECT  a.keyID,
        count(b.keyID) AS countOccurencies
FROM    `keywords - occurencies` a
        LEFT JOIN `keywords` b
            ON a.keyID = b.keyID
WHERE   a.keyID IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) AND 
        DATE BETWEEN '2013/01/25' AND '2013/01/27'
GROUP   BY a.keyID
```

**UPDATE 1**

Based on the example records, you need to do the following,

- interchange the tableNames
- put this condition `DATE BETWEEN '2013-01-25' AND '2013-01-27'` on the `ON` clause of join.
- (*optional*) use `ALIAS` so you can get rid of the backticks other than tableNames

query,

```
SELECT  a.keyID,
        count(b.keyID) AS countOccurencies
FROM    `keywords` a
        LEFT JOIN `keywords-occurencies` b
            ON a.keyID = b.keyID AND
               b.DATE BETWEEN '2013-01-25' AND '2013-01-27'
WHERE   a.keyID IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) 
GROUP   BY a.keyID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7fbc/8)

Comment: Thank you for the corrections, but the above query still doesn't return the 0 result row.

Comment: can you give sample records that we can play with?

Comment: Sure, i added them to my question.

Comment: I think you need to interchange those tablesname, and put the condition of the at the time of joining them, not on the `WHERE` clause. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7fbc/7

Comment: Moving all the left-joined column dependencies into the left-join clause (instead of in AND clauses) worked perfectly for me as well.  Thank you!

Comment: I had no idea you could add condition onto the join! Thanks for this

Answer (score 2):

Put a back tick  on `date`::

```
SELECT 
`keywords`.keyID, 
count(`keywords-occurencies`.keyID) as countOccurencies 
FROM `keywords-occurencies`  
LEFT JOIN `keywords`  ON `keywords-occurencies`.keyID = `keywords`.keyID 
WHERE `keywords-occurencies`.`keyID` IN (1,2,3) AND `date` BETWEEN '2013/01/25' AND '2013/01/27'
GROUP BY `keywords-occurencies`.`keyID`
```

Comment: @SashiKant regarding the question just now... there's no point really commenting ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things.  You need to group by the id on the *first* part of the left outer join.  You then need to count what is one the *second* side.  For a right outer join, the order is the opposite:

```
SELECT k.keyID, count(ko.keyID) as countOccurencies 
FROM `keywords-occurencies` ko
      RIGHT JOIN `keywords` k
      ON ko.keyID = k.keyID 
WHERE k.`keyID` IN (1,2,3) AND date BETWEEN '2013/01/25' AND '2013/01/27'
GROUP BY k.`keyID`
```

The reason for this has to do with the left outer join.  It keeps everything in the first table, even when there are no matches.  So, that is where you get the complete list.  As for the count, you want to count matches.  If you count the id in the first table, you will always get at least 1.  Counting the id in the second table allows you to get 0.

Notice I also added aliases to your table to make the query more readable.

Comment: Thanks but query still doesn't return the 0 result row.

Comment: @SportBilly . . . Based on the names of the tables, I think you want a right outer join -- my guess is that the keywords table contains all the keywords and the occurrences might have 0 values.  I modified the query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Changing that to `LEFT JOIN` worked for me:

```
SELECT k.keyID, count(ko.keyID) as countOccurencies 
FROM `keywords-occurencies` ko
      LEFT JOIN `keywords` k
      ON ko.keyID = k.keyID 
WHERE k.`keyID` IN (1,2,3) AND date BETWEEN '2013/01/25' AND '2013/01/27'
GROUP BY k.`keyID`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To insert code in your posts, use the "Code sample" button, not the "Code snippet" button. The snippet button is only for HTML/CSS/JS